# Nusach of Jewish Renewal

Tags: heterodox, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard, reform-judaism, nusach-ari

[Jewish Renewal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Renewal) was founded by Reb Zalman, who was formerly Chabad Lubavitch, which follows Nusach Ari. Is the nusach followed by Jewish Renewal derived from Nusach Ashkenaz, Nusach Sefard or Nusach Ari?

Comment: As I understand from Wikipedia, the whole point of the movement was to introduce Kabbalistic and Chassidic thought into liberal Judaism, which definitely have less (explicit) presence in Nusach Ashkenaz.

Comment: Their siddur is freely available online doing exactly the Google search you'd think to do. If by 'Nusach Ari' you mean a modified version of Nusach Ashkenaz incorporating some Chassidic and Kabbalistic elements, it's definitely that. If you mean the Chabad nusach specifically, I've never used it so I don't know their nuances.